# template option explanation in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How works `template` option in Rails `database.yml` file? According to postgres documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html we can set template when create database. Does it mean, that `template` option in `database.yml` works only on `rake db:create` task? Or this option works also in other cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found, that template option used only on database creation: [template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/471bec310d1ecc50311f18b545df1d789d6bac0d/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb#L29) and [create_database](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/87eb1a26da0b1385af07a8347dcfd32998a614ee/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L21)

```
  ....
  when :template
    " TEMPLATE = \"#{value}\""
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add template like:

```
development: &defaults
  # (...)
  encoding: utf8
  template: template0

test:
  <<: *defaults
  # (...)

production:
  <<: *defaults
  # (...)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is when this option `template: template0`  works? Only on `rake db:create` ?